# Initializing Java variable

Tags: java, initialization

I am starting a process. And later I want to be able to destroy the said process then start it again.

```
Process myProcess;

try {
    myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pathToMyProgram);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then I do stuff. And later:

```
try {
    myProcess.destroy();
    myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pathToMyProgram);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is at the line

```
myProcess.destroy();
```

There is an error because myProcess can be uninitialized at this point. Also I can't do something like:

```
myProcess = new Process();
```

I know I could solve this by putting everything in a big `try{}` statement but is there another way ?

EDIT: I cannot do the null check either, the error is: the process might not be initialized.

But thanks to you I then tried to do `Process myProcess = null;` and now it works ! Thank you and sorry for the bad question.

I'm removing the process tag for relevance. And edited title.

Comment: you can do null check `if (myProcess!=null) myProcess.destroy();`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I cannot do this test either, because it doesn't allow me to test the potentially uninitialized process. I'm adding part this to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing so solved my problem. Sorry for the newb question.

```
Process myProcess = null;
```